# Calling method using main thread from secondary thread

Tags: c++, c, linux, gtk

I have called a method using a secondary thread.
From inside the method i need to call a method from main thread.

here is the structure

```
void main_thread_method()
{

} 

void secondary_thread_method()
{

//do something here

  call main_thread_method() here using main thread

}

pthread thread1;

pthread_create (&thread1, NULL, (void *) &secondary_thread_method, NULL);

pthread_join(thread1);
```

Comment: As the data in one thread can be accessed from another thread in the same process, I don't see what the problem is? Do you want to transfer control to another thread for some calculations? In that case check out semaphores and condition variables.

Comment: @All: In Objective C/C++, there is an API where u can invoke method using main thread from secondary thread. Actually, I need to call gtkWindow objects which should be called only from main thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your main thread is running a message pump you can post a message somehow to execute a function when your message is received.

Otherwise have a simple queue ( appropriate locking of course ). Add enough data into the queue so that main_thread_method can be called. (args etc).  Periodically poll the simple queue for new messages in the main thread and process them.

Comment: +1 There are better methods than polling but essentially this is the correct technique. Basically the main thread can not just sit around and wait on join it must actively be listening somehow.

Comment: +1 for PostMessage to a main-thread window.  I usually use an invisible window created at startup with RegisterClass() and CreateWindow() for all posts to the main thread.  I transfer the target window instance in wParam and a parameter in lParam.  The WndProc then calls a message-handler on whatever window is passed when it gets the posted message.  The 'lParam' parameter can be anything, often I pass a class containing a 'command' enum, (as well as other stuff, eg. data buffers), that, via a switch, can call any number of methods on the main thread to update controls etc.

Comment: @Martin I think op is looking for linux solution

Comment: @parapurarajkumar - Oops! 'message pump' etc. distacted me from the original tags.  Editing now..

Comment: In the case of non-Windows OS, communication with the main thread is dependent up on the main thread design.  You should submit a suitable signal to whatever the main thread usually waits on when not busy.

Answer (score 1):

I understood you want to invoke, from secondary thread, a method that must run in main thread. This is not possible. Invoked functions runs in the same thread. You mus use any kind of multi-threading communication method like semaphores, messages pooling, conditions, etc.